# How to print (part of) a man page?

Tags: printing, man

The question is: **how do you print only part of a man page?**

Currently I do `zcat manpage.1.gz | vim -` and just remove everything I don't want to print. Then I pass that through groff and lpr. Are there better methods?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to easily print a man doc I usually do it the graphical way:

```
man -Hfirefox command
```

Then you can print certain pages in your web browser. This isn't as powerful as doing it through the command line but it's a lot easier to get right since you can actually see what you're printing ahead of time. This may be important if you want to print a landscape document or something of that sort.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you can print a whole man page at once, in plain monospaced text, by doing something like

```
man mc | col -b | lpr -P printername
```

Or to print it "pretty" (Serif font, bold, italics etc.) by doing

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/mc.1.gz | groff -man -Tps | lpr -P printername
```

As this basically sends a postscript file to the printer, you can also save it to a PostScript file by doing

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/mc.1.gz | groff -man -Tps > mc.ps
```

But I have no idea if you can easily extract a certain page, pages, or sections.

Comment: Some versions of the man command have a `-t` option as a shortcut for outputting postscript so you don't have to find the `.1.gz` file and type that long command, you can just `man -t foo | lpr`. On selecting sections, I doubt it can be done cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
man ls | sed -n "5, 8p;8q" > print_this.txt # get lines 5 to 8
```

Then print with

```
lp -d <printer> print_this.txt
```

(Hint: The option (`-o`) switches of lp are very useful!)

But better yet: open in your editor, then mark the region. In Emacs:

```
M-x man RET ls
```

Then

```
M-x print-region
```

For this to work, the variable `printer-name` must be set. Or, use switches to lpr. (I see that you do not use Emacs, but this is of course possible in your editor as well.)